# Get data from dynamically added input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an input field where the user enters article ID and compare. 
On first application load, the user has by default three input field, but he can dynamically add more inputs.My problem is, how to get the entered value of dynamically added inputs and send them to URL
for example like this (I know how to put id's to URL, this is only for showing what I need)
`'https://someurl.com/' + ID + '/someurl'`

I try to make function where I pass entered value to controller but I get `UNDEFINED`

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.choices = [{id: ''}, {id: ''}, {id: ''}];

 $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
  $scope.choices.push({'id':newItemNo});
 };

 $scope.showChoiceLabel = function (choice) {
  return choice.id === $scope.choices[0].id;
 }

 $scope.submitChoice = function (name) {
  alert('url ' + name + ' url');
 }
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family:Arial;
 color:#333;
}
label {
 font-weight:bold;
}
#choicesDisplay {
 margin-top:1em;
}
.form-group {
 width:70%;clear:both;
}
.form-group input {
 float:right;
 width:60%;
 padding:.3em;
}
button {
 background-color:#3f7ebc;
 color:white;
 padding: .5em .7em .5em .7em;
 font-weight:bold;
 border:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
 <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Custom Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script>
   document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
   <label for="choice" ng-show="showChoiceLabel(choice)">Choices</label>
   <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add another choice</button>
   <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="enter id">
  <button ng-click="submitChoice(choice.name)">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="choicesDisplay">
   {{ choices }}
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your submit button inside the div

Comment: Thnx, I made mistake in snippet, I fix this. Problem is, i get only one value, but I need all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because, your `submit` button is outside of the scope.

1) **You either move the button inside loop to submit individually**

or

2) **Submit multiple instances by loooping all.**

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.choices = [{id: ''}, {id: ''}, {id: ''}];

 $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
  var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
  $scope.choices.push({'id':newItemNo});
 };

 $scope.showChoiceLabel = function (choice) {
  return choice.id === $scope.choices[0].id;
 }

 $scope.submitChoice = function (name) {
  $scope.choices.forEach(function(choice, index){
  alert('url ' + choice.name + ' url');
  if(choice.name)
  {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
        $scope.first = choice.name;
        break;
    case 1:
        $scope.second = choice.name;
        break;
    case 2:
        $scope.third = choice.name;
        break;
    case 3:
        $scope.fourth = choice.name;
        break;
}
console.log($scope.first,$scope.second,$scope.third,$scope.fourth)
  }
  
  })
  
 }
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family:Arial;
 color:#333;
}
label {
 font-weight:bold;
}
#choicesDisplay {
 margin-top:1em;
}
.form-group {
 width:70%;clear:both;
}
.form-group input {
 float:right;
 width:60%;
 padding:.3em;
}
button {
 background-color:#3f7ebc;
 color:white;
 padding: .5em .7em .5em .7em;
 font-weight:bold;
 border:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
 <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Custom Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script>
   document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
   <label for="choice" ng-show="showChoiceLabel(choice)">Choices</label>
   <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add another choice</button>
   <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="enter id">
      
  </div>
    <button ng-click="submitChoice()">Submit</button>
  
  <div id="choicesDisplay">
   {{ choices }}
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet for second example**

**PS:** As per your request, based on the index of the choice in loop, assigned the `choice names` to respective `scope variables` using `switch case`.

Comment: @Arter, Please run my snippet, you will get all your entered values.

Comment: hi, thnx for your answer. Now, in console.log(choice.name); I get NAME @Sravan one by one, in console. User can have max four dynamically added input. Is there any way to set every value to new $scope. I mean if user in first input enter 991, in second 992, in third enter 993 and in four input enter 994, i want to add first input to $scope.first = 991; $scope.second = 992; etc...

Comment: @Arter, updated my answer according to your requiremwnt. Please check

Comment: Glad to help you. :)

Comment: One more question :)  I do everything from your answer. And I console.log($scope.first, $scope.second, $scope.third, $scope.fourth); and 23 undefined undefined undefined
23 undefined undefined undefined
23 undefined undefined undefined
undefined 234 undefined undefined
undefined 234 undefined undefined
undefined 234 undefined undefined
undefined undefined 2 undefined
undefined undefined 2 undefined
undefined undefined 2 undefined
undefined undefined undefined 324
undefined undefined undefined 324
undefined undefined undefined 324

Comment: Soo, how to prevent switch case from delete previous value?

Answer (score 1):

choice.name in submit choice is undefined because your submit button is outside the scope of ng-repeat

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
          <label for="choice" ng-show="showChoiceLabel(choice)">Choices</label>
          <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add another choice</button>
          <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="enter id">
</div>

<button ng-click="submitChoice(choice.name)">Submit</button>
```

If you want to submit 1 choice you can place your button inside ng-repeat. If you want to submit all choices you can iterate through choices in your controller.

**Update**

you can use below code to iterate through choices and submit if name is not undefined

```
angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(value, key) {
    if(value.name != undefined)
        $scope.submitChoice(value.name)
});
```

Comment: Can you pls help me with this iterate. Do I need to push everything in array or what? Need to iterate in passed choice.name? Thnx